# Cannot figure out parselong and strings (Android app)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have read alot of the questions regarding this subject and everything I have read seems to indicate I am doing the correct thing, but still the problem remains (frustrated).  I am having a user enter a edit text value to use for a countdown timer that I know needs a long (primitive) variable.  So I used Long.pasreLong(Stringvarible) to get the long.  This isnt working. I have added a try catch and it seems to be indicating there is a problem with the parsing, but I cannot figure out the issues.  See the section of code below:

```
  editText_Time.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener(){

        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
          boolean handled = false;
          if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE||
                    actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
                    event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                    event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

              startTime_String = editText_Time.getText().toString();

              //Something's wrong with the parse long portion 

              startTime_Long = Long.parseLong(startTime_String);

                //  try {
                //  startTime_Long = Long.parseLong(startTime_String);       
                //  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + e.getMessage());
                //  }

              startTime = startTime_Long;

              countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
              return false;
          }
          return handled;
      }
  });
```

Comment: Have you printed the `EditText` value to check if it has the right value?

Comment: So, I figured out what was wrong.  Parselong was fine, there was no NumberFormatIssue or bad parsing.  I was taking the entered number in to the as miliseconds and not multiplying by 1000 thus the countdown was too fast so it would just end.  Thanks for the responses...

Answer (score 0):

If `getText()` returns empty `CharSequence` you will get `NumberFormatException`.

In order to avoid it you can do the following

```
startTime_String = editText_Time.getText().toString().trim();
if (startTime_String.length() == 0) {
    startTime_Long = 0;
} else {
    startTime_Long = Long.parseLong(startTime_String);
}
```

And of course, the EditText should be numeric

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  The EditText is numeric. I have used a toast to check the  startTime_String is getting passed to the countdown method, ensuring the variables are not reset or not passing correctly.